# R studio doesn't find objects in my function

Tags: r, function, loops

I’m new to programming and I’m currently writing a function to go through hundreds of csv files in the working directory.

The files have tons of NA values in it.

The function (which I call it corr) has two parameters, the directory, and a threshold value (numeric vector of length 1 indicating the number of complete cases).

The purpose of the function is to take the complete cases for two columns that are sulfate and nitrate(second and third column in the spreadsheet) and calculate the correlation between them if the number of complete cases is greater than the threshold parameter.

The function should return a vector with the correlation if it met the threshold requirement (the default threshold value is 0).

When I run the code I get back two of the following:

1. A + sign in the console

OR

2.The objects I created in the function can't be found.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold=0){
  filelist2<- data.frame(list.files(path=directory, 
                                    pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE))            

  corvector <- numeric()

  for(i in 1:length(filelist2)){
    data <-data.frame(read.csv(filelist2[i]))
    removedNA<-complete.cases(data)
    newdata<-data[removedNA,2:3] 


    if(nrow(removedNA) > threshold){
      corvector<-c(corvector, cor(data$sulfate, data$nitrate )) 


    }


  }
  corvector   
}
```

Comment: A `+` sign in the console means R is waiting for more input to complete the expression- it usually means you haven't closed off one of your parens/curly braces somewhere.

Comment: objects defined inside the function won't be available outside that scope. e.g. try `f = function() local.object = 1; f(); local.object`

Comment: @dww which object is being called outside the function in the OP's example?

Comment: @Richard OP stated "The objects I created in the function can't be found". It's anyone's guess which objects OP is trying to access

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `nrow(removedNA)` does what you think it does. To replicate the example I use the `mtcars` dataset.

```
data <- mtcars # create dataset
data[2:4, 2] <- NA # create some missings in column 2
data[15:17, 3] <- NA # create some missing in column 3
removedNA <- complete.cases(data)
table(removedNA) # 6 missings indeed
nrow(removedNA) # NULL removedNA is no data.frame, so nrow() doesn't work
newdata <- data[removedNA, 2:3] # this works though
nrow(newdata) # and this shows the rows in 'newdata'
#---- therefore instead of nrow(removedNA) try
if(nrow(data)-nrow(newdata) < threshold) {
    ...
}
```

NB: I changed the `>` in `<` in the line with threshold. I guess it depends on whether you want to set an absolute minimum number of lines (in which cases you could simply use `nrow(newdata) > threshold`) as threshold, or whether you want the threshold to reflect the different number of lines in the original data and 'new' data.